# Don't want android-studios default animation on the bottom navigation drawer

Tags: android, material-design, bottomnavigationview, material-components-android, material-components

I want no animation on selecting a menu item on the bottom action bar just to change the colour of the selected menu item
I have 4 menu items on the bar.

I tried using the helper class but still didn't work.
I was able to put labels on each item whether selected or not,but the default animation did not stop .

```
package com.shubham.exp;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.util.Log;
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationItemView;
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationMenuView;
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
public class helper {
    @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
    public static void disableShiftMode(BottomNavigationView view) {
        BottomNavigationMenuView menuView = (BottomNavigationMenuView) view.getChildAt(0);
        try {
            Field shiftingMode = menuView.getClass().getDeclaredField("mShiftingMode");
            shiftingMode.setAccessible(true);
            shiftingMode.setBoolean(menuView, false);
            shiftingMode.setAccessible(false);
            for (int i = 0; i < menuView.getChildCount(); i++) {
                BottomNavigationItemView item = (BottomNavigationItemView) menuView.getChildAt(i);
                //noinspection RestrictedApi
                item.setShifting(false);
                // set once again checked value, so view will be updated
                //noinspection RestrictedApi
                item.setChecked(item.getItemData().isChecked());
            }
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            Log.e("BNVHelper", "Unable to get shift mode field", e);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            Log.e("BNVHelper", "Unable to change value of shift mode", e);
        }
    }
}
```

'

There were no error message.

Comment: after creating hlper class .did you write this also  helper .disableShiftMode(bottomNavigationView);

Comment: Try This .....
menuView .enableAnimation(false);
menuView .enableShiftingMode(false);
menuView .enableItemShiftingMode(false);
menuView .setTextVisibility(false);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found  a way thanks to https://android.jlelse.eu/disable-shift-label-animation-from-bottom-navigation-android-b42a25dcbffc 
Just keep dimens of text constant in dimens.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <dimen name="design_bottom_navigation_active_text_size"
        tools:override="true">12sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to avoid the ripple animation on `BottonNavigationView` you can use something like:

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomNavigationView"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/item_icon_tint"
    app:itemRippleColor="@null"
    .../>
```

Comment: Gives AAPT error  attribute itemRippleColor not found

Comment: @AmAteur8BP Are you using the version 1.1.0 ? (currently the latest is 1.1.0-alpha10)

Comment: upgraded to the alpha10 now but still the annimation is there

Comment: @AmAteur8BP What kind of animation? Maybe I am missing something.

Comment: The default: On clicking an item it kind of uplifts the selected...it increases the size of the label and icon

Comment: Are you using the style Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomNavigationView ?

Comment: no  '<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView></ <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView>

Comment: Ok it is the component. In the component add style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomNavigationView"

Comment: Error inflating class androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout

Comment: @AmAteur8BP check the updated answer about the stye

Comment: Check the stacktrace. It is quite strange, also because the animation is not in the guideline.

Comment: I've also checked the demo of the material components. The default behavior doesn't increase the size of the label and the icon.

Comment: Is there a way i can explain it by showing it to you by showing screen recorder.

Answer (score 0):

Material Design.

App dependency to your Gradle file to the latest version.

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha10'
```

and in your bottom navigation code add below lines

```
BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
navView.clearAnimation();
```

I hope this will help

Comment: the app runs but still there is annimation